# TWRP Recovery stuck at splash screen

Tags: cyanogenmod, recovery-mode, twrp

I'm using TWRP 3.0.2 on my LG G3. At first it worked fine and I used it to install Cyanogenmod 14. But now I can't boot into TWRP anymore, it just hangs forever at the splash screen. Android still boots fine.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve the problem by removing the SD card before booting into TWRP, like suggested [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/LGG3/comments/4a2uu4/twrp_30_hangs_on_boot_into_recovery/d0wy48r/).